# How to say that the region is not elementary?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Let $C \subset \Bbb R$ be compact and let $\phi,\psi : C \to \Bbb R$ be continuous. $$S = \{(t,x) \mid x \in C, \phi(x)\leq t \leq \phi(t)\} \subset \Bbb R^2$$
is called an elementary region in $\Bbb R^2.$ We can generalize it into any $\Bbb R^n$.

> My Question: We know to check elementary region but how to say that the region is not elementary?

Example: The annular region between the two circles $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=4$.